# Поиск по таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос в mysql

```
aId as id,
(SELECT aLogo FROM table WHERE table.aId=published.aId ) as logo,
(SELECT aUser FROM table WHERE table.aId=published.aId) as user,
(SELECT aLabel FROM table WHERE table.aId=published.aId) as label,
```

и т.д.
Как добавить к этой выборке поиск по полям? 
Что-то вроде

```
WHERE `field1` LIKE @s OR `field2` LIKE @s OR `field3` LIKE @s;
```

Но при этом `WHERE table.aId=published.aId` должна остаться обязательно.
И еще. 
Я, видимо, неправильно делаю:

```
SET @s:='$_GET["s"]';
```

Подскажите, как правильно=)))

Comment: `$s=$_GET['s'];` 
   
Также не забывайте ставить кавычки, если вы ищите по строковому типу.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, может, стоит для начала заменить три одинаковых селекта из таблицы `table` на `JOIN`? Покажите структуру ваших таблиц. Cделайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com